# Laravel blade section

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I just get to know that we can write section with this:

```
@section('sectionname','data')
```

What is the difference between the above method with the below method?

```
@section('sectionname')
'data'
@stop
```

Is it a proper way to write with the first method? Although, during my testing, it does not need `@stop` for the first method. But is it the best practice that we need to put it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For writing small string in the sections you can use

```
@section('sectionname','data')
```

and to write multiple lines of html you will use

```
 @section('sectionname')
    'data'
 @stop
```